# Enable wrapping in code blocks (vuepress)

Tags: markdown, vuepress

When writing markdown (in vuepress), is there a way to enable wrapping in code blocks?

Some bash commands in code blocks are very long so vuepress is displaying scrollbars. I would prefer if I could enable wrapping.